# Resolved: ESP8266 works when arduino UNO reset pin is grounded

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I'm setting up PIR and esp8266 with arduino UNO.
First my esp8266 doesn't work after alot of research my esp8266 start working when I put arduino UNO reset pin to ground.
But now my arduino UNO does not run any program and I'm not able to use PIR with this wifi module.
Any help will be appreciated
[image]

Only one extra thing is that reset pin is set to GND pin.

Comment: Show how you have all of this wired together.

Comment: I've added wiring image to question please check. Only one extra thing is that reset pin is set to GND pin

Comment: Please check the specs on your ESP8266 module.  The IO pins are not 5V tolerant.  That would explain the problems you are having.  I see you are powering it from 3V3 but the Uno's GPIO pins are all 5V.

Answer (score 5):

The RESET of the UNO puts the ATMega328P (the MCU of the UNO) into an electrically inert state when it is connected to GND.  It is not *supposed* to be running your sketch when it is being held in reset.  It is, roughly speaking, electrically disconnected from everything else on the board.  This allows you to use the UNO as though it were a USB to TTL serial cable.

If you want to be able to run a sketch on the UNO while it uses the ESP8266, you'll need to **not** hold reset to GND and you'll also, practically speaking, need to choose a different set of pins for communicating with it, as D0 and D1 on the UNO are the same signals used to for the ATMega328P to talk to the host and used for programming the UNO via its bootloader.  On the UNO, you'd instead need to use SoftwareSerial (or something similar) and pins other than D0 and D1.  **[Update: see the [original poster's own answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/80883/70020) containing the guide they ultimately used, making use of SoftwareSerial on pins 10 and 11]**

The ESP-01 can run Arduino sketches using the [ESP8266 Arduino](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino) core and it may make a great deal more sense to not involve the UNO at all, and instead connect the distance sensor more or less directly to the ESP8266.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, can you send me any link to blog or youtube tutorial to setup it up like you said

Comment: I don't have any links for you offhand.  But you're likely to find some if you look for people using UNO together with the ESP-01.  You'll notice a lack of grounding reset, and the use of SoftwareSerial or something else to do the communication from the UNO to the ESP-01.  You should keep in mind that these parts do not run at the same voltage, so you need to be careful with interfacing them.

Comment: Ok, I tried few solutions with software serial as I remember and I got no response in my serial monitor. I'll check if can find something more similar. Thank you

Comment: If the only things connected to the UNO are PIR sensor and the ESP-01, I strongly encourage you to move the sketch code onto the ESP-01 and find a tutorial on using one of those PIR sensors directly with the ESP-01.  `esp-01` and  `"PIR sensor"` as search terms turn up a number of probably useful articles.  If I get a look at them later to vet one, I may integrate it into the answer.

Comment: I've posted answer with link to blog that helped me resolve issue. Thank you for moving me in right direction

Answer (score 1):

So, I got it working with this information on this blog
Few things, my serial.begin(115200) where as in blog its 9600
Thanks @timemage for moving me in right direction
[1]: https://medium.com/@cgrant/using-the-esp8266-wifi-module-with-arduino-uno-publishing-to-thingspeak-99fc77122e82